# executing angular functions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

i have a html button like this

```
<md-button type="button"  ng-click="commentDelete(item,$index)" aria-label="change address" >
<md-icon md-svg-icon="img/ic_highlight_remove_24px.svg"></md-icon>
</md-button>
```

this is my controller

```
var commentDelete = function(item,index){
   console.log('working')
} 

$scope.commentDelete =commentDelete;
```

this is working without any problem.
but if i try something like this

```
var myCtrl= function(item,index){
   return {
      commentDelete : function(item,index){
        console.log('working')
      }
   }
} 

 $scope.commentDelete =myCtrl.commentDelete
```

then it doesn't trigger the **commentDelete** function. why is that? thanks in advance

Comment: I think, myCtrl must be object to use this convention (myCtrl.commentDelete).
So, you should declare myCtrl as object.

var myCtrl= {
      commentDelete : function(item,index){
        console.log('working')
      }
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you assign to the `$scope.commentDelete`  a property of the `myCtrl`(myCtrl is a function, and it tries to find a `commentDelete` on it or in the `Function`). 
`myCtrl` is only a function, which returns an object with the function `commentDelete`.

```
var myCtrl= function(item,index){
   return {
      commentDelete : function(item,index){
        console.log('working')
      }
   }
} 

 $scope.commentDelete = myCtrl.commentDelete
```

If you call `myCtrl` and then get the commentDelete, it will work

```
$scope.commentDelete = myCtrl().commentDelete;
```